# Do CUDA texture object's support 3 channel textures?

Tags: cuda, textures

The older [texture references](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-reference-api) in CUDA only support 1, 2, and 4 channel textures (e.g., I would pad RGB colors to RGBA). Do the new CUDA [texture object](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-object-api)'s support a 3 channel texture?

(I currently don't have access to a newer nVidia card to try it with and the documentation started to make my eyes bleed looking for an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general description of [texture memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-memory) which applies to both texture references and texture objects, it states:

> The **texture object or the texture reference** specifies:
>
> ...
>
> The type of a texel, which is restricted to the basic integer and single-precision floating-point types **and any of the 1-, 2-, and 4-component vector types** defined in `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `longlong`, `float`, `double` that are derived from the basic integer and single-precision floating-point types.

So, no, 3-component vector types, even with texture objects, are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for finding that -- must be a power of 2 thing! Kind of a bummer in my case since then I need to pad out all the RGB values into RGBA values

Comment: There might be some clever techniques such as described [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/481747/cuda-programming-and-performance/is-texture-60-float3-3-62-possible-cudaerrorinvalidchanneldescriptor/post/4933251/#4933251) to texture from a 3-channel image, but without knowing your actual data storage format and needs, it's hard to say.